# React Native - data duplicates on firebase data update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm using React Native and firebase for the application, where I'm using 'on' for listening to database changes, but whenever data is updated, my data doubles (getting duplicates of every object). I tried resetting the data before forEach loop but it returns the empty data on the last iteration. I was using array earlier and then I tried using Set but still the same result. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Here is my code:

```
friendPost = () => {
    let that = this;
    let res = new Set();

    firebase.database().ref("/Manifest User/"+this.state.currentUsername.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ "/"+
        this.state.currentUsername+"/Friends").on("value", function (snapshot) {
        // let result=[];
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            if(childSnapshot.key !== 'Friend Requests'){
                res=[];
                firebase.database().ref("/Manifest User/"+childSnapshot.key.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+"/"+childSnapshot.key
                    +"/Profile Posts/").on("value", function (postSnapshot) {

                    postSnapshot.forEach(function(miniSnapshot){
                        if(miniSnapshot.key !== '~default') {
                            let url;
                            let urlTemp = miniSnapshot.val().post.match(/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/);

                            if (urlTemp !== null){
                                url = urlTemp[0];
                                if (urlTemp[0].includes("youtu")) {

                                    url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+urlTemp[0].substr(urlTemp[0].lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                                }
                                else if (urlTemp[0].includes("vimeo.com")){
                                    url = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/"+urlTemp[0].substr(urlTemp[0].lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                                }
                            }

                            let postString = miniSnapshot.val().post
                                .replace(/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/, '');

                            res.push({
                                postDate: miniSnapshot.key,
                                postImage: miniSnapshot.hasChild('postImage') ? miniSnapshot.val().postImage : '',
                                post: postString,
                                username: miniSnapshot.hasChild('postUserName') ? miniSnapshot.val().postUserName : '',
                                comments: miniSnapshot.hasChild('postComments') ? miniSnapshot.val().postComments : [],
                                likes: miniSnapshot.hasChild('postLikes') ? miniSnapshot.val().postLikes : [],
                                url: url,
                                actualPostString: miniSnapshot.hasChild('post') ? miniSnapshot.val().post : '',

                            });
                        }

                    });
                    // alert(JSON.stringify(res))
                    that.setState({friendPosts: Array.from(res)});

                }.bind(this));
            }

        });

    })
};
```

Comment: We're you able to figure this out? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

A reason for this to be happening is your component re-rendering. The code where you are calling this function is called twice i.e. on a re-render.